# Angular ng-repeat error display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code inside a form tag, I would like to have some error text appear underneath the checkboxes however at the moment I am unable to get it to work with the current setup I have below. What am I doing wrong here?

ticketing/competition_checkboxes.html

```
<div ng-repeat="compCbx in competitionCheckboxes track by $index">
    <input ng-attr-id="cc_comp_{{ $index }}" ng-model="compCbx.isChecked" name="cc_comp" ng-attr-label="cc_comp_label_{{ $index }}"
           type="checkbox" ng-required="compCbx.checkRequired" ng-checked="compCbx.isChecked" form-blur />
    <label ng-attr-id="cc_comp_label_{{ $index }}" ng-attr-for="cc_comp_{{ $index }}" class="fake-label">
        <i ng-attr-id="cc_comp_cbx_{{ $index }}"></i> <p ng-bind-html="compCbx.text | to_trusted"></p>
        <span class="error-msg error-tnc" ng-show="{{formName}}.cc_comp.$touched && {{formName}}.cc_comp.$error.required">
            You must agree to enter the competition
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The current output on the page is

[image: The form before submission]

[image: The form after submission]

As you can see the Terms and Conditions checkbox validates correctly, however that is because it is not in an ng-repeat

The Terms and conditions has this code

```
<input id="cc_tnc" ng-model="cc_tnc" label="cc_tnc_label" name="cc_tnc" type="checkbox" ng-required="cc_tnc != true" form-blur>
        <label id="cc_tnc_label" for="cc_tnc" class="fake-label">
            <i id="cc_tnc_cbx"></i> <p>I have read and agree to <a href="@Model.TermsUrl" target="_blank">terms and conditions</a></p>
            <span class="error-msg error-tnc" ng-show="{{ formName }}.cc_tnc.$touched && {{ formName }}.cc_tnc.$error.required">
                    You must agree to the Terms and Conditions to make a purchase
            </span>
        </label>
<ng-include src="'ticketing/competition_checkboxes.html'"></ng-include>
```

Form Blur directive

```
directive('formBlur', function(setErrorState) {

        //set element on dirty
        return {
            restrict: 'A,E',
            require: ['^form'],
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                var form = scope[ctrl[0].$name];

                element.bind('blur', function() {

                    scope.$apply(function() {

                        console.log("Error in blur");
                        form[attrs.name].$touched = true;
                        setErrorState(element, form[attrs.name].$valid);

                    });
                });

                scope.$watch(form.$name + '.' + attrs.name + '.$valid', function(validity) {

                    console.log("In watch");
                    console.dir(form[attrs.name]);
                    if (form[attrs.name].$touched)
                        setErrorState(element, validity);

                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: What is the content of "fake-label" css class? What is the current output; please provide html rendered by your browser.

Comment: @osmanraifgunes the fake-label class simply contains some formatting for margins etc. Its not effecting the display. I have added more details to the question as requested

Comment: @osmanraifgunes updated with new details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ng-required="compCbx.checkRequired"` to `required="compCbx.checkRequired"`

[Jsfiddle working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/10413/)

I don't know why it is working ;)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working in the fiddle? If I set checkRequired to false it still expects the checkbox to be checked... I believe that the actual issue is caused by attempting to validate using `ng-show="{{formName}}.cc_comp.$touched && {{formName}}.cc_comp.$error.required"` since the name field on the input are not allowed to have configurable names. Using angular subforms seems to get closer to a solution, but its still not right....